# What is the best way to reinforce/mend a fraying elastic strap by hand?

Tags: sewing, fabric

I would like to mend the elasticized shoulder straps of a dress. The straps are fraying along the edges. The material of the dress is synthetic, with a close-knit weave and four-way stretch. I do not have access to a sewing machine, so I would be hand-sewing. I understand that zigzag stitches are commonly used with stretchy fabrics, but I'm unsure if that would be the best way to reinforce an edge. I also considered a blanket stitch, but I don't know if that would work with a stretchy fabric. What would be the best stitch or mending method for this situation?

Comment: Can you add a photo of the fraying section? Or if that's not possible, at least clarify whether the fabric is knitted or woven.

Comment: Is there fabric covering the elastic? What is the width of the strap?

Comment: Is the strap made with the same material as the dress? It might be cut on the bias and made into a strap, which makes it seem stretchy but doesn’t use elastic.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to add a picture, but this is what the dress looks like: [link](https://www.outdoorvoices.com/products/w-The-Exercise-Dress). The fabric seems to be woven, and while the fabric itself is stretchy, it is definitely tacked over a stretchy elastic strap.

Comment:  you can totally replace that with bra strap that can be purchased at a fabric/craft store or online. That will take time and be a tedious fix. But The other ideas of masking the fray should give you more fun ways to keep that dress working. fabric glue and rhinestones, bedazzle it, sequins have fun and jazz it up!

Comment: Those are great suggestions for when the straps finally give out! Thank you so much for your helpful ideas (and apologies for thanking the wrong user below!) :)

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue with the exact same dress! Only wore my Exercise Dress twice and the straps are shredding. I did get a replacement from customer service, but I wanted to pass on [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgHZL.jpg) of my strap in question because it sheds some light on the construction. It seems to be an elastic band covered by the stretchy fabric. Hope that helps, and good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned, I also might start with a whipstitch just to clean up the edges. Cut away the fray or use fray check before whip stitching by hand. Whipstitch is just a fast and looser blanket stitch.

Later, I would remove the old straps and tack on new ones.

Some ideas:

- matching elastic (easiest method and it comes in more colors these
  days)
- ribbon
- bias tape
- trim - look up trim at your favorite fabric/craft store for other ideas (lace, twisted cord, eyelet, etc.)
- You may be able to cut the bottom of the dress and recreate the strap with the same fabric, but it won’t be as stretchy. If you need it to be stretchy and use this method, cut the length longer than needed for each side and wrap it around the correct length elastic. You’ll want to use an iron to make it easier to hand stitch.

If you use ribbon, It’s an opportunity to give it new straps and then decorate the dress with ribbon fringe somewhere else on the dress.

Have fun!

Comment: thank you @fixer1234 i appreciate your help formatting my answer! 

Comment: Thank you @fixer1234! That's very helpful- I hadn't thought of using a whipstitch, which would both help finish an edge and be more "flexible" or stretchy than a blanket stitch. The fraying is currently minor (about 5mm in length), so hopefully I'll get some mileage out of mending until I need to replace the straps.

Comment: @mifftiff, I can't take credit, I just helped format the list.  The content is the work of Not The Face.  :-)